# Load SQL File to HTML Table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I have a file input that should load a sql file into a html table using javascript(not jquery). Is it possible to do this? I've been searching though forums and tutorials about this but I failed to see one. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Also I want to load SQL files dynamically.

Sample SQL File content:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.4.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Apr 27, 2017 at 12:22 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.11
-- PHP Version: 5.5.3

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `usi_customerdb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `customer`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `C_ID` char(17) NOT NULL,
  `C_Client` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_Type` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_Status` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_Meter_Type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_AccountNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_Lastname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_Firstname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_Middlename` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_Suffix` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_Establishment` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_MaritalStatus` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_Nationality` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_Gender` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_Birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_TIN` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C_SysEntryDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `C_ModifiedDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `C_ModifiedBy` char(17) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`C_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `C_AccountNumber` (`C_AccountNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `customer`
--

INSERT INTO `customer` (`C_ID`, `C_Client`, `C_Type`, `C_Status`, `C_Meter_Type`, `C_AccountNumber`, `C_Lastname`, `C_Firstname`, `C_Middlename`, `C_Suffix`, `C_Establishment`, `C_MaritalStatus`, `C_Nationality`, `C_Gender`, `C_Birthdate`, `C_TIN`, `C_SysEntryDate`, `C_ModifiedDate`, `C_ModifiedBy`) VALUES
('', NULL, 'I2', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2017-03-13 01:04:47', '2017-03-13 01:04:47', ''),
('EST20161215-00001', 'meralco_cavite', 'C', NULL, 0, '1258', '', '', '', '', 'MY BOSS OFFICE SUPPLIES AND GEN. MDSE.', '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '126-754-467-000', '2016-12-15 08:05:25', '2016-12-19 14:48:19', 'NGC19910101-00001'),
('EST20161215-00002', 'meralco_cavite', 'I', 'FDISC', 0, '1034', 'SOCCERFIELD', 'MARK', 'D', '', 'MEC ELECTRONICS PHILIPPINES CORPORATION', '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '000-289-786-000', '2016-12-15 08:07:08', '2017-04-21 00:58:52', 'NGC19910101-00001'),
('EST20161219-00001', 'meralco_cavite', 'I', NULL, 0, '1847', 'SOCCERFIELD', 'MARK', 'D', '', 'MEC ELECTRONICS PHILIPPINES CORPORATION', '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '000-289-786-000', '2016-12-19 09:42:56', '2017-04-18 07:00:05', 'NGC19910101-00001'),
('EST20161219-00002', 'meralco_cavite', 'C', NULL, 0, '2400', '', '', '', '', 'JUGRO TRANSPORT INT''L. (PHILS.) CORP.', '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '000-150-071-003', '2016-12-19 09:46:27', '2016-12-19 09:46:27', 'NGC19910101-00001'),
('EST20161219-00003', 'meralco_cavite', 'C', NULL, 0, '2087', '', '', '', '', 'THE PREMIERE INS.', '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '001-006-578-000', '2016-12-19 09:50:08', '2016-12-19 09:50:08', 'NGC19910101-00001'),
('EST20161219-00004', 'meralco_cavite', 'C', NULL, 0, '1951', '', '', '', '', 'BLITZ VENTURES CUSTOM BROKERAGE', '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '130-125-141-000', '2016-12-19 09:52:35', '2016-12-19 09:52:35', 'NGC19910101-00001'),
('EST20161219-00005', 'meralco_cavite', 'C', NULL, 0, '2643', '', '', '', '', 'LAMBERT WILLIAMS LOGISTICS INC.', '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '213-017-058-004', '2016-12-19 09:57:10', '2016-12-19 09:57:10', 'NGC19910101-00001'),
('EST20161219-00006', 'meralco_cavite', 'C', NULL, 0, '2662', '', '', '', '', 'ALLIANCE MANSOLS INC.', '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '007-837-136-000', '2016-12-19 10:01:03', '2016-12-19 10:01:03', 'NGC19910101-00001'),
('EST20161219-00007', 'meralco_cavite', 'I', NULL, 0, '2218', '', '', '', '', 'CHAMSEN CORP.', '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '231-933-810-000', '2016-12-19 10:08:05', '2016-12-19 10:08:05', 'NGC19910101-00001'),
('EST20161219-00008', 'meralco_cavite', 'I', NULL, 0, '2681', '', '', '', '', 'RICHKIM INTL CORP', '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '008-913-777-000', '2016-12-19 10:10:34', '2016-12-19 10:10:34', 'NGC19910101-00001'),
('EST20161219-00009', 'meralco_cavite', 'I', NULL, 0, '1006', '', '', '', '', 'CHANG CHUEN COTTON PAPER MFG CO LTD PHILS INC', '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '000-290-425-000', '2016-12-19 10:13:10', '2016-12-19 10:13:10', 'NGC19910101-00001');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: What does the input file contain? Where is the SQL file that you want to load stored in?

Comment: I just want to load sql file using a file input onchange stored on local disk, just like loading a csv file into html table.

Comment: There are parsers for node.js, but AFAIK, not for javascript in a browser. There are others written in PHP. Most won't handle the insert statement as far as getting the data to populate an HTML table. Writing a purpose specific parser wouldn't be that hard unless it needs to be able to deal with the select, create table, etc. statements. If all you need is to parse the insert data, that shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Why do you not want to insert the file into the database and query it? That would be a lot easier